# When is it ok to use variables in regression models as independent variables that may also have been used in deriving the dependent variable?

Tags: regression, correlation, independence

I've used a previously published land-type category dataset (with five categories) as the base for investigating how a subset of two of the land-type categories vary with different variables, including climatological rainfall and elevation. The original land-type category dataset was verified against ground based observations and has a high accuracy, so I was using it as a proxy for the ground-truth within my investigation. However, elevation was also used as an input variable in modelling the original data (a different elevation dataset from the one I used within my model). Does the issue of circularity between my use of elevation in the linear regression and its use in the original land-type category dataset invalidate my results? Is there a threshold of accuracy between modelled and ground based observation data, that would then allow for the derived dataset to be used in someone else's research, without them having to worry about which variables were included in the original model?

Comment: This question is not clearly worded to me. Can you edit the post to use consistent terminology (is a land-type category dataset somehow different from a land-type dataset?). Are the "two categories" based on collapsing some of the "5 categories" and is the category the same as the dependent variable? Further, I think it would be better understood if you avoided any *statistical* language - dependent variable, regression model, etc. - and rather focus on the science you are doing.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've updated the post to use consistent terminology for the land-type category dataset. I was referring to the same dataset. There are a total of 5 categories, but my study was only interested in 2 of these categories (two different types of wetland forest). I am aiming to determine if climatological (seasonal rainfall/temperature) and geographical factors (including elevation above sea level) contribute to one type of forest prevailing over the other in different regions.

Comment: I'm trying to think of a more intuitive title for this question, but I'm not sure how to describe it without referring to dependent/independent variables.

Comment: I think the wording of the title is perfect.  I'm also interested in any connections that might be made to https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/396964/term-for-two-variables-that-are-too-close-for-control .